# No key frames when sending H263 with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I'm trying to stream H263 via RTP with gstreamer 1.0. It works just fine aside from no key frames being sent. The command line looks like this:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=ball ! avenc_h263 ! rtph263pay pt=34 ! udpsink host=10.0.75.196 port=25782 sync=true`

The result is that it starts from black and only works with changes thereafter. Could it have anything to do with avenc_h263 using stuff that only H263+ or H263++ handles?

I would be very grateful for any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem! Standard rtp-payload-size is 0. Changing this parameter to anything above zero, I tried 1 and 20, makes it run smooth and with full frames.

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=ball ! avenc_h263 rtp-payload-size=10 ! rtph263pay pt=34 ! udpsink host=10.0.75.196 port=25782 sync=true`